# Not able to read and edit file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Here is what I have tried:

```
>>> with open("symbols.raw") as f:
...     text=f.readlines()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1694: character maps to <undefined>
>>> with open("symbols.raw",encoding='utf-16') as f:
...     text=f.readlines()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 61, in _buffer_decode
    codecs.utf_16_ex_decode(input, errors, 0, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 7500-7501: illegal encoding
>>> with open("symbols.raw",encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     text=f.readlines()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 7: invalid start byte
```

When I tried using the binary mode then it got loaded but I am not able to understand how to read and edit my own data in it.

```
>>> with open("symbols.raw",'rb') as f:
...     text=f.readlines()
...
```

Here is the file: [symbols.raw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QRl2vY7g8LuAOsOCRbEUBoY7omCR3lxt/view?usp=sharing)

Please let me know how I can read it in human interpreted way and write my own data in it.
Here is the [format of the symbols.raw file](https://github.com/EA31337/MT-Formats/blob/master/symbols.raw.h).

Comment: why don't you read the file as binary and then decode it to utf-16?

Comment: @Avenger789 won't that give the same problem as reading the file with the utf-16 encoding as shown in the second error?

Comment: As you see I have tried. But not working. Secondly, I have said I am not able to understand the binary. I have written in the question.

Comment: You can use 'rb' to read it and then use the `struct` mod to interpet it,you can read the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct

Comment: @Avenger789 tried your idea: Error: `UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

Comment: is your .raw an image file? possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439831/open-raw-image-data-using-python

Comment: No it is not an image file. That is why I am facing a lot of trouble. I got one idea reading through the internet: https://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?p=11585927#post11585927 But that is not working since I do not have the license of WinHex.

Comment: One way is to use HxD to view the bytes and extract it accordingly.  When reading in as bytes and remove the headers.

Comment: Please can you guide me with the HxD? It is something new for me...

Answer (score 2):

you may use with `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`:

```
with open("symbols.raw", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    text=f.readlines()
```

Comment: Wow, I can edit it. But please can you help me in editing the file also. Because I am not able to understan dthe binary file. Itried, hence I found something that is related to the format. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I am trying to read and edit the file. Already mentioned in the same question. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell python to ignore or replace the errors by specifying the `errors="ignore"` parmater of the open function, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616678/unicodedecodeerror-in-python-when-reading-a-file-how-to-ignore-the-error-and-ju) answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read it off as bytes first then convert it into a list because python do not allow you to edit binary strings.

```
def read_file_bytes(file_name):
    in_file = open(file_name, "rb")  
    data = in_file.read() 
    in_file.close()    
    return data

file_data = list(read_file_bytes(file_name))
```

Alternatively you can slice the bytes according to your symbols files that you have provided, (assuming size is the number of bytes)

```
file_data = read_file_bytes(file_name)
name = str(file_data[:12])
unknown_2 = int(file_data[1628:1628 + 4])
```

To write a new file you can just do the following:

```
def write_bytes_to_file(file_name, bytes):
    out_file = open(file_name, "wb")
    out_file.write(bytes)
    out_file.close()

all_bytes = bytearray(name) + bytearray(unknown_2)
write_bytes_to_file('new_file_name.raw', all_bytes)
```

Comment: But how I can edit my data into it? Please can you add that part too? I have that in question as well that I am trying to read and edit the file

Comment: you can just edit the values according already. Or do you mean to write a new raw file

Comment: I guess writing new file is always safe. I am trying to add my own values into the file. That's why I am very confused as I am dealing with binary data.

Comment: To be fair this question has 2 parts possibly more, and every thing you need has already been provided. All that is left for you is to read the file according to the sequence that you have provided.