# Reading .raw file from XRD device

Tags: python, file, binary

After performing some XRD (X-Ray Diffraction) of my samples a .raw file is generated (the spectrum, a graph). I want to open this file to further process it (plot it, analyze its peaks, etc), but sadly I have not find the way to do it. This is the first time I need to delcare this is the first time I work with .raw files.

I have been googling a lot how to read it with python but without success. I came up with this post [open .raw image data using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439831/open-raw-image-data-using-python) but sadly in my case does not work. I did try:

`raw = rawpy.imread('Tur_50_4h_3_70grad_002_inc_cont.raw')`

But that gave the following error:
`LibRawFileUnsupportedError: b'Unsupported file format or not RAW file'`

Does anyone know how to read these type of files? My goal will be to read it so maybe I can, apart from plot it, do some peak analysis and so son. I have to say this is the first time I face a .raw file (:

The file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AnEIGs2TLJ_0JcuayAW4Loh3LErbChku/view?usp=share_link

Thank you so much in advance, much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pyXRD library: https://github.com/PyXRD/PyXRD